# Statelessness Vs Overloaded POST in REST for Account transfer example

Tags: rest

I'm reading RESTful Web Services (OReilly). The author mentions statelessness (Application state as opposed to Resource state) as one of the main features of ROA.

Later in the book, when he takes the example of Account transfer to explain about Transactions, he mentions the option of exposing the transactions as resources as more RESTful than the overloaded POST.

Exposing Transactions as resources:
To summarize from the book:

To transfer $50 from Checking ($200) to Savings ($200)
End result: Checking ($250) and Savings ($150)

A checking account resource is exposed at `/accounts/checking/11` and savings account resource is exposed at `/accounts/savings/55`

```
POST /transactions/account-transfer HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

which returns

```
201 Created
Location: /transactions/account-transfer/11a5
```

Putting $150 in Checking

```
PUT /transactions/account-transfer/11a5/accounts/checking/11 HTTP/1.1
Host example.com

balance=150
```

and Putting $250 in Savings

```
PUT /transactions/account-transfer/11a5/accounts/savings/55 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com

balance=250
```

and finally putting committed=true

```
PUT /transactions/account-transfer/11a5/1.1
Host: example.com

committed=true
```

This, he says this can be implemented by building a queue of actions associated with the transaction. From the book:

*When the transaction is committed the server might start a database transaction, apply the queued actions, and then try to commit the database transaction.*

My question is:

Isn't maintaining a queue of actions on the server stateful (Application state)? And hence Statelessness is violated?

**Editing after Kai Mattern's Answer**

I think what you are saying is that this queue of actions is resource state and not Application state. The book also makes this distinction and says resource state is Ok but not Application state.

But when you think about Statelessness w.r.t the fact that you can distribute a stateless application across load balanced servers, the above series of POST and PUTs won't let you do that. A load balancer should send all requests to 1 particular server because a queue of actions is maintained on that 1 server. Otherwise, if the above resources are split to reside on multiple machines (to enable load balancing) something like a RESTful two phase commit transaction may be required.

So, we are looking at 2 options Overloaded POST Stateless App Vs 2 phase commit Stateless App for this particular example.

Is that the case?

Comment: To clarify on you addition: statelessness actually allows you to spread all requests over all servers of a cluster as long as the database is the same. As long as you hack a transaction into separate database actions, all servers have the same information. What you see in the example with the last commit=true is not a database commit, but  a hint to whatever takes the action from there on to gather all that stuff and create a real transaction out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statelessness does not mean that the application is completely clueless. It just means that the application does not remember its state by other means than the url, cookies and more importantly the database.

This leads that you should not save data in something like a server session, unless that session information is mapped to something like a session resource.

So as long as the actions are mapped to a resource, it has a chance to be stateless.

Please note, that mapping actions to urls will often tempt you to create action like urls like /transactions/startTransaction - which is wrong. Think of resources as nouns - not verbs.

So for example:

```
logging in -> create a session resource 
logging out -> delete the session resource
```

What you example shows, is exactly that behaviour: You create a resource (an account transfer). You modify it to contain all relevant data. Then you change its state (yes, state) by committing it.

As soon the commit flag is written, the backend will process this transaction. This might be done with putting the transaction into a queue. But that part is not part of the frontend - and statelessness might or might not stop there.

So, to answer your question: Don't mix data state with application state. Maintaining a queue  of actions as resources is stateless. Maintaining actions in server memory (stateful application server session) is not.

Comment: If I understand it right, you are talking about resource state Vs Application state. I edited the question with more doubts. Can you please clarify?